# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, session

I have a request in laravel which is I needed to store in session what I'm try to do is store all the request in a session to lesson the coding which is this one:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    session()->put('quotation',  $request);
    return 'success';
}
```

What it does is it is storing all the request to session but I am encountering an error

(1/1) Exception
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

I'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: you can't store the actual Request object because it has closures as properties, they can't be serialized ... what are you actually trying to store, the inputs from the request?

Comment: 5 requests from input text(Example: Name,Address,Contact,Email,Age), I need to mass store them so I dont need to store them one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Request object has Closures as properties. You probably don't need the entire Request object but only the inputs. If you only need the inputs you can save the array of inputs:

```
$request->session()->put('quotation', $request->input());
```

`quotation` will contain an array of the inputs.

Comment: `$request->all()` is a better alternative to `$request->input()` - the latter only gets the inputs while the former will also include files.